# SOAP request from in-document C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap

I have an .aspx file that I'm trying to make a call to an API service (hosted on our servers internally).

I'm trying to do this from within the same file (nothing behind the scenes) - is this possible?

Here is my .aspx file:

```
<%@ Language="C#" debug="true"%>
<HTML>
    <script runat="server" language="C#">
        public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //setup Request
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest) 
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("https://my.fully.qualified.server/EMSAPI/");  
            //format our SOAP request
            string strRequest = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" + 
                            "<soap12:Envelope" +
                            " xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"" +
                            " xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"" +
                            " xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">" +
                            "<soap12:Body>" +
                                    "<GetAllBookings xmlns=\"http://DEA.API.WEB.SERVICE/\">" +
                                            "<UserName>username</UserName>" +
                                            "<Password>password</Password>" +
                                            "<StartDate>"+
                                            "2016-08-08T00:00:00.000"+
                                            "</StartDate>" +
                                            "<EndDate>"+
                                            "2016-08-09T00:00:00.000"+
                                            "</EndDate>" +
                                            "<BuildingID>36</BuildingID>" +
                                            "<ViewComboRoomComponents>false</ViewComboRoomComponents>" +
                                        "</GetAllBookings>" +
                            "</soap12:Body>" +
                            "</soap12:Envelope>";
            //String xmlString = strRequest; 
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding(); 
            byte[] bytesToWrite = encoding.GetBytes(strRequest); 
            request.Method = "POST"; 
            request.ContentLength = bytesToWrite.Length; 
            request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction: \"https://my.fully.qualified.server/EMSAPI/\"");
            request.ContentType = "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"; 
            System.IO.Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream(); 
            newStream.Write(bytesToWrite, 0, bytesToWrite.Length); 
            newStream.Close(); 
            System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); 
            System.IO.Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream(); 
            System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(dataStream); 
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    </script>
    <body>

    </body>
</HTML>
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Source Error:


Line 58:     newStream.Close(); 
Line 59: 
(THIS IS BOLDED) Line 60:     System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); 
Line 61:     System.IO.Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream(); 
Line 62:     System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(dataStream);
```

Any thoughts on what might be going wrong or how to further troubleshoot this?

Comment: Anything could have caused this.  Your best bet is to trace out the exception that was thrown on the API service.

Comment: But the form looks okay and appropriate? First time dealing with C# - so I'm hopeful a second set of eyes might catch a stupid mistake I've made.

Comment: Frankly, it's going to be faster chasing down the error on the server.  There's a good chance that whatever exception is being thrown there will point you right at the problem.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance - what is the best way to chase down the error? Just digging through logs on the server?

Or is there additional code I can do to display the error clientside?

Comment: Try running the Event Log Viewer on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up talking to our system admins and making sure our web directory had been configured as an application.

Then I created a new web application and added a Service Reference pointing to the API.

- Right click on References
- Click 'Add Service Reference'
- Put in your
  API URL (to your .wsdl location)
- Name your service reference
- Access
  it programatically (i.e.: *theService.SoapClient client = new
  theService.SoapClient();*  )

Then do what you need to do with the methods the API provides you in the References.cs document of the Service Reference!